# Cómo Reconstruir una Tabla o BDatos MySQL y Remover Privilegios si no tengo el usuario con sus privilegios?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un sistema PHP y MySQL que corre bien pero no puedo mostrar el contenido de la tabla `articulo` y no permite agregar mas artículos. No tengo el usuario que posee los privilegios ni su contraseña.
¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto o como podría reconstruirla?
¿Se puede reconstruir toda una base de datos para un sistema que ya está hecho o arreglar la tabla `articulo` solamente? De poderse, ¿Cómo se haría?
De antemano, muchas gracias por su tiempo y ayuda.

Pude ver el ERROR al notar que en localhost el sistema funciona al 100%, pero al subirlo a un hosting gratis, no funciona el módulo `Agregar articulo`.

Comment: Y no tienes ningún otro tipo de acceso a la base de datos? con un usuario con accesos superiores podrías editar los privilegios de la tabla (agregar o modificar usuarios).

Comment: La BD fue creada por un tercero y creo que le puso algo de restricciones, privilegios, superusuario o algo de eso. Pienso que lo hizo para proteger su autoria, pero el sistema se ofrece GRATUITO en youtube y me hice de una copia q funciona d maravillas en mi equipo, pero ya la he subido a 2 hosting gratis q usan FTP y se ve corriendo todo perfecto "Aparentemente" y cuando voy a agregar articulos, no muestra lo guardado el sistema actua como si no guarda y me voy directo por phpMyAdmin y veo q si se almacena un registro. Pienso q NO es falla del módulo agregar.php porq funciona bien en mi pc

Comment: pero si la `BD` la tienes que importar en algún momento al servidor, quiere decir que tienes permisos suficientes como para alterarla. lo más probable es que el problema esté en otra parte (alguna configuración que tenga que ser distinta en `localhost` que en el server por ejemplo). Sería necesaria más información al respecto para poder darte más ideas.

Comment: Gracias amigo, excelente tu respuesta. Ya fui a probar todo desde el principio y no parece problemas de base de datos o privilegios sino como tú dices mas bien creo que es una rutina del programador para evitar que el sistema corra 100% en un servidor, ya que eso es lo unico que hace, bloquea la tabla articulos inicia agregar articulo y cuano guarda no muestra el inventario sino que se queda pegado alli diciendo 0 registros de 0, apesar de mostrar el aviso de: Articulo agregado con éxito. No se como hacer en ese caso

Comment: Sería necesario que aportaras más información para poder sacar cualquier deducción. sin leer código o saber a qué sistema te refieres es muy difícil adivinar.